# Interact with an element inside a class with "hidden" attributes

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, tinymce

I am trying to interact with this iframe which is a Tinymce editor.

[HTML code of the website can be seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFbi8.png)

When I try to locate the element using the following xpath

```
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='assessment_questions_attributes_565794_text_ifr']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element1)
print("Element Clicked!")
```

I get a

> NoSuchElementException

Previously I had no problems accessing Tinymce editors on the same website using the code below, more on this can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203210/handle-tinymce-window-with-python-selenium-and-phantomjs)

```
driver.execute_script("tinymce.get('{0}').focus()".format(id_of_element)
driver.execute_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('{0}')".format("Hello World")
```

However in this case, it throws this exception

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript
>   error: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

One more interesting thing, if I try to access the elements using Javascript, I get nothing.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mce-content-body")
```

But when I manually change all the "hidden" attributes to "visible" and hidefocus to "0" in DOM the Javascript code works.

Comment: You need to switch to the iframe. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358

Comment: @Trapli I tried that too, it doesn't work.